# creating 2 popup's programatically(calling 2nd popup from 1st one) in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I need to create 2 popup's programmatically and each popup should contain one INPUT box and one OK button and one CANCEL button.

Upon clicking on the first popup OK button i have to bringup the second popup.

I am new to jquery mobile, i looked into many docs but i didnt get proper way to do it.

i tried to do it something like this. but didn't worked.

```
var $popUp = $("<div/>").popup({
        dismissible : false,
        theme : "a",
        overlyaTheme : "a",
        transition : "pop"
    }).bind("popupafterclose", function() {
                    //remove the popup when closing
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

How can I do it in my js file?..

Thanks:).

Comment: your popups would kill you, use dialog instead :P sorry i mixed between you and another user.

Comment: @Omar how can i do that?. can you please help??

Comment: you almost done in your code above. afterclosing the first popup, create another one and open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 Popus can not be active at the same time.

There's a workaround, and here's my old example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8Arrt/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#index',function(e,data){    
    $('#test-button').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#MyFirstPopup').popup('open', {x : 100, y : 500, positionTo : 'origin'});
    });    

     $('#popup-button').on('click', function(e) {
         setTimeout(function(){$('#MySecondPopup').popup('open', {x : 100, y : 100, positionTo : 'origin'});},100)
         $('#MyFirstPopup').popup('close');
    });
});
```

Basically if you want to open second popup you must close the first one. That's why we need setTimeout to opet second popup after the first one has been closed.

Comment: thanks for the answer it's working. but both the popup's are positioning to window even though i have defined position to origin.

Comment: I have updated my answer, this is how you use positionTo inside a  popup('open') function. You can also do it with data-position-to attribute but you can't use coordinates.