# Dialog does not open in .done .fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I've got a strange problem here

Wen i call this popup  $("#popupDialog").popup( "open" ) in jquery mobile bevor the JSON call everything is fine and works, although when i try to call it in the .done section - nothing, nadda.

The strange thing is that alert("saved") works fine but popup seems to have it's problems.

A jquery dialog works also fine.

```
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify($('Form').serializeObject());

    var jqxhr = $.post( "serviceCALL",jsonData, function(jsonData) {

        })
        .done(function() {
             $("#popupDialog").popup( "open" );
        })
        .fail(function() {
            $("#datafail").popup( "open" );

        })
        .always(function() {
            $("#datasaving").popup( "close" );
        });
```

Comment: `.popup()` what is it?

Comment: ohh its jQuery mobile's popup, just googled.

Comment: Do you get anything in the console?

Comment: Also, an obvious question but I have to ask, have you added `data-rol="popup"` to the popup element?

Comment: `data-role`, not data-rol :p

Comment: thx for your comments, the console was ned giving me any hint. the data-role="popup" ist set and it behave as it should if i call it e.g. before the json call. when the json data is returned the .done gives me an alert but if i try to call the dialog there nothing happens ... really strange.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to initialize your popup first by adding data-role="popup" to your div like so:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
</div>
```

or programatically call :

```
$( "#popupDialog" ).popup();
$("#popupDialog").popup( "open" );
```

[Source](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/popup/)

Comment: thx for you answer, here is the markup which works fine outside the .done section: <div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog"  style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all">

   <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
    <h1>Speichern</h1>
   </div>
   <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
    <h3 class="ui-title">Daten erfolgreich gespeichert.</p>
    <a href="#" data-role="button"  data-rel="back" data-transition="fade" data-theme="b">Ok</a>  
   </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

found the answer here

[creating 2 popup's programatically(calling 2nd popup from 1st one) in jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563567/creating-2-popups-programaticallycalling-2nd-popup-from-1st-one-in-jquery-mob)

the problem is the popup itself - i think there must be some kind of sync problem when closing one and opening the other one 'cause this was the case with my 2 popups - the closing event of one popup closed the newly created popup ... strange but true.